# Find your way up the polymorphic tree to one parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, arel

I have a simple polymorphic association

```
#comment.rb
belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
#post.rb
has_many  :comments, :as => :commentable                                        
accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, :allow_destroy => true
```

So in IRB I can do, Post.comments, or Comment.comments.

But how can I find the parent post?

As in Comment.post ?

I can currently get their by doing a series of `.commentable`'s. For example :

```
Comment.find(1).commentable.commentable
=> Post(:id => ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go up the list, e.g.:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    def parent_post
      c = self
      c = c.commentable while c.is_a?(Comment)
      c
    end
end
```

But that can get VERY slow if they are deeply nested (`n` db queries).
I suggest you simply store `parent_post_id` with comments if you need performance.

Comment: GREAT IDEA about parent_post_id!! Also yes, its so slow, my grandma could flip flap jacks on her back faster than that.

Comment: you really shouldnt program when you are stoned dude... (**cough** **cough**) :)